# Collecting informations from file to Map<K, V>

Tags: java

I have a document that contains something like this:

32 : { 15, 25, 65 }

43 : { 90, 45, 12 }

65 : { 50 }

And I want to map these strings and I tried:

```
public static void Collect(String entry)
{
     entry = entry.replace("{", "");
     entry = entry.replace("  "," ");
     String[] lines = entry.split(" }");
     Map<Integer, Integer[]> map = new HashMap<>();
     List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
     for(String s : lines)
     {
         if(!s.contains(":"))
            continue;
         int owner = Integer.parseInt(removeReverse(s, ":", 1).replace(" ","");
         if(s.contains(",") {

            if(s.contains(",")) {
            for(String s1 : s.split(",")) { 
            s1 = removeUntil(s1,":",1);
            temp.add(Integer.parseInt(s1));
            }}
            map.put(owner, (Integer[]) temp.toArray());
         }
         else {
            temp.add(Integer.parseInt(formatter(s,"{","}"));
            map.put(owner, (Integer[]) temp.toArray());
         }
     }
}
```

Referenced methods:

```
public static String formatter(String text,String start,String end)
{
    if(text.length() == 0) return null;
    int s = text.lastIndexOf(start)+start.length();
    int e = text.indexOf(end);
    return text.substring(s,e);
}

public static String removeUntil(String str, String c, int st)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    str = sb.reverse().toString();
    for(int i = 0;i<st;i++)
        str = str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf(c));
    sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    str = sb.reverse().toString();
    return str;
}
public static String removeReverse(String str,String c,int st)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    sb = new StringBuilder(removeUntil(sb.reverse().toString(),c,st));
    return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

After all, I tried to print "map's entrySet" in main method as

```
map.entrySet().forEach(Operator::print);
```

Operator.print method ->

```
public static void print(Object o)
{
    System.out.print(o);
}
```

But, output is an exception. Out ->

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1954)
at Operator.removeUntil(Operator.java:23)
at Operator.removeReverse(Operator.java:31)
at Operator.readHashTable(Operator.java:122)
at MainScreen.main(MainScreen.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: Now is the perfect time to learn using a debugger.

Comment: @JBNizet So I can learn with your helps.

Comment: All the IDEs work the same way. You put a breakpoint on a line of code, by clicking in the left margin of the code. Then you execute the program by clicking on the button displaying a bug icon rather than the one displaying a play icon (usually). The program executes until it reaches the line where the breakpoint is. Then you can use the buttons of the debug view (or keyboard shortcuts) to execute the program line by line. And you can watch the value of every variable in the watch view. Experiment. Try it. You won't break anything.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. I will try it, if I can't again, I will notify you.

Comment: @JBNizet I checked them, until map everything is OK. problem is on map.put(). I think..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression to match it and then you can obtain the group of integers for each entry using a split on the second group.

```
static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) \\: \\{\\s+([^}]+)\\s+\\}");// : \\{(?:\\s+(\\d+),?)\\s\\}$");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    InputStream resourceAsStream = FileRead.class.getResourceAsStream("/numbers.txt");
    String content = IOUtils.toString(resourceAsStream);
    System.out.println("collec: " + collect(content));
}

public static Map<Integer, Integer[]> collect(String content) {
    Map<Integer, Integer[]> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer[]>();
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
//        System.out.println("content: " + content);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String strKey = matcher.group(1);
        Integer intKey = Integer.parseInt(strKey);
        String intGroupStr = matcher.group(2);
        String[] intValueStr = intGroupStr.split(", ");
        Integer[] intArray = new Integer[intValueStr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < intValueStr.length; i++) {;
            intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(intValueStr[i]);
//                System.out.println("intArray[" + i + "] " + intArray[i]);
        }
        map.put(intKey, intArray);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: We aren't here to program for them, we are here to help. Don't offer code, provide solutions.

Comment: @lpinto.eu just offering a different approach that he might not have thought of

Comment: @Beggs probably this is a school assignment, or something like that. And now he will copy past your code, without understanding it. If you suggested the use of regular expression (that I thik is to advanced for him), without the code, that would be an interesting suggestion.

Comment: @Ipinto.eu You may be right but sometimes, especially for newbies (like me), sharing some codes to solve problems gives us inspiration more than we had. Do not worry about sharing something.

Comment: @Ipinto.eu No, I like to learn programming so that I will research for regex, I will COMPLETELY check these codes and understand it.

Comment: I can see your point @lpinto.eu.  I could have kept it more general, more pseudocode.  However, I have seen in my experience, as a student and a teacher's assistant, those who copy assignments without understanding, have a difficult time on exams.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug on your algorithm. I copied your code into my IDE, and I successfully recreated the same error. The problem is the 3rd call to `removeUntil()`. Further analysis reveals that `removeUntil` is trying to find work with the number 52 that is not in there (it's mixing 15 25, in the 1st line).

Your code is messy and confusing. My suggestion to you, is: simplify your algorithm, review in your mind (or using paper), how would you do it, if it was fiscal objects with printed numbers. Probably you would split the lines first, then split by the ':' and only in the end split by ','